# dynamically allocated char

Tags: c++

```
int main()

{
   char *second= new char("hello");
   char *first="hi";
   char third[]="new";
}
```

I am new to c++ and don't really understand how char works, why the first one give a compiler error, and what are the differences of those 3 way of declaration , the strength and benefits of declaring it in a particular way.

Thanks

Hmm, as someone mentions that the second form is read only, why could I Change it. suppose I have the code below

```
 int main()

{
   char *second= new char("hello");
   char *first="hi";
   char third[]="new";
   first="world";
}
```

code like above will still execute, why is it so? , then which form is better if I want to read an input but don't know the size of the string?

Answer (score 14):

Know that

```
"abc"
```

allocates static storage somewhere, which lasts the whole program lifetime. You cannot write to that storage, so C++ gives it the type `char const[N]` (an array of N constant characters). Now, the following makes a pointer point to that storage

```
char *first = "hi";
```

Since that drops a `const`, that way of initializing the pointer is deprecated. That it works at all is just to keep backward compatibility with C, where a string literal does not have a const type (but is still read only). Prefer the following instead

```
char const *first = "hi";
```

In constrast, the last way you have shown copies the string literal's content to an array, which will be writable, and be sized so the string literal just fits into it.

```
char third[] = "new";
```

If you do that in a function, then as all variables, that array will be cleaned up when you leave its scope. Now, the first way you have shown is different. It creates a character dynamically. You could have initialized it like this

```
char *c = new char('A');
```

And since that happens dynamically, you need to tell the compiler explicitly when it should free the memory

```
delete c;
```

But you cannot initialize the character with a string literal. What you probably had in mind is creating storage dynamically, initialized with the string literal. That's not possible using `new`. The only form of initializing a dynamic array is to zero it out, but you cannot directly-initialize with the content of a string literal or another array. For this form of using `new`, there is rarely a need to do that directly. If you want, you can do it by creating a dynamic array of the right size, and then copy bytes from the string literal to that buffer

```
char *c = new char[sizeof "hello"]; // sizeof "hello" will give 6
std::strcpy(c, "hello");

delete[] c; // delete[] is for deleting dynamic arrays
```

Remember that this is quite low-level, and i recommend you to use strings

```
std::string s = "hello"; // s.size() gives you its size
```

It completely manages memory for you. Concatenation, indexing and that stuff is available too.

Comment: +1. The only thing I would add is a small bit about char vs. char*. Reading the OP's question, it seems like he's confused about char vs. char*/c-style strings.

Comment: good summary man.
Don't you think there's a problem with newcomers relying on std::string too much. It makes C++ too much like Java and when you have to work with char* you're lost.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try to explain in code:

```
// your code
char *first="hi";
// this is the memory location of the string, assigned by the compiler
// sizeof(first) == sizeof(char*) == 4 (usually, lets not get into this right now)
char *first = 0x12345;


// your code
char third[]="new";
// means, the following:
char third[4];
third[0] = 0x6E; // ascii code of 'n'
third[1] = 0x65; // ascii code of 'e'
third[2] = 0x77; // ascii code of 'w'
third[3] = 0x00; // strings in C end with NULL
// note that sizeof(third) is still sizeof(char*), but this 
// time you statically allocated sizeof(char)*4 for the whole array
```

More reading for you:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII
- http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson9.html